# Disappearing galaxies

Tags: general-relativity, big-bang, relative-motion

According to the cosmological model of the expanding universe, the distant (diametrally opposite) galaxies have bigger and bigger relative comoving speed, and this speed (which is not a relative speed in the sense of SRT) can ultimately become bigger than c.

Is the following speculation consistent with GRT: someone films the far sky and on the film, at a moment t = T, a distant galaxy disappears? [The galaxy was to see on the film at t < T but no more at t = T because the relative comoving speed becomes > c in this really moment. Galaxies being big, we can imagine also an apparent extinction interval T0 < t < T1.]

This question is related to:

[Is General Relativity compatible with relative speeds bigger than $c$ between two inertial frames?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/242993/is-general-relativity-compatible-with-relative-speeds-bigger-than-c-between-tw)

as it resulted from the discussions it generated there.

Comment: It doesn't disappear, it simply gets redshifted to a frequency of essentially zero. That's no different from something disappearing trough the event horizon of a black hole. Given that electromagnetic waves are quantized and that there are limits to our detector sensitivity, at some point these objects become practically undetectable.

Comment: I thought also about redshift, but some wave-length beyond visible will always become visible. It is hard to say when does the e m spectrum end. However by v > c there must be apparent extinction. No matters how ultraviolet, all e m radiations travel with speed c.

Comment: There is a "last photon", if that is what you mean and in practice the object becomes undetectable, but in terms of classical redshift it simply shifts exponentially towards zero frequency (i.e. it looks like an over-damped wave solution).

Comment: True. This question is a duplicate. But I don't know if the unique answer given there solvesit completely.

Comment: I think this discussion if very helpful http://curious.astro.cornell.edu/about-us/104-the-universe/cosmology-and-the-big-bang/expansion-of-the-universe/616-is-the-universe-expanding-faster-than-the-speed-of-light-intermediate and a link therein  http://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0310571v2.pdf